# How to focus a hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JS and trying to make an input field that that only appears when the user types anywhere on the page. Currently, the appearing of the input field works but once it's visible, the user still has to click into the field to type in it.

I would like it to work like:

- User presses "S"
- Field appears with "S" typed in it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/RNrore

```
var searchArea = $(".search");

searchArea.hide();

$(document).ready(function()  {

  $( "body" ).keydown(function() {
    searchArea.show();
    searchArea.elements['input'].focus();
    console.log("worked!");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

What is `searchArea.elements['input']` supposed to do ?

Try it like this instead, using jQuery's `find` method

```
$( "body" ).on('keydown', function() {
    searchArea.show().find('input').focus();
});
```

[**PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwZbzL)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `find` the `input` element within the seach area, then call `focus()` on it:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  var $searchArea = $(".search").hide();

  $("body").keydown(function() {
    $searchArea.show();
    $searchArea.find('input').focus();
  });  
});
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPGOXe)

Answer (score 0):

Or just set id to input field (<input autofocus="autofocus" `id="hid_inp"` >)
and use `$("#hid_inp").focus();` instead of `searchArea.elements['input'].focus();"`